# How can Celery workers poll Prometheus to see if there are any alerts?

Tags: kubernetes, queue, celery, prometheus, azure-aks

I am running a Kubernetes cluster in AKS. The purpose of the cluster is to receive requests, put them through a Calculation service (which are pods that each run a Flask server) and present the result on an API endpoint the user can poll.

A problem I encountered is that when there are many requests arriving at the same time, the Calculation pods get overwhelmed. That is why I used Celery to implement a queuing system. Celery uses RabbitMQ as a broker and Postgresql as a result backend. It receives the requests through a Flask server.

The plan was to somehow poll the Calculation pods to see if there are resources available. Based on that answer, the Celery pods either send the request to the Calculation service or waits until there are available resources. For this resource-polling system I first considered using the Kubernetes Metrics Server, but the Metrics Server [github](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) says: *Don't use Metrics Server when you need: An accurate source of resource usage metrics, Horizontal autoscaling based on other resources than CPU/Memory. For unsupported use cases, check out full monitoring solutions like Prometheus.* Which is why I decided to use Prometheus. I have it set up now and am receiving the resource-alert I described above like expected.

I know that Prometheus can send alerts to other places. But is there also a way for Celery to ask Prometheus if it has any alerts happening?

Comment: Prometheus has metric ALERTS. It shows firing and pending alerts. You can query it in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if there are any alarms registered by Prometheus by sending a GET request to:

> api/v1/alerts

More can be read on this [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) documentation page.